# PHP login script json error

Tags: php, android, authentication

i have an error in my php script which i am executing in postman to be used in android studio.the response part is not executing its giving an error

```
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '$response' (T_VARIABLE) in
<b>/home/u259428939/public_html/Login.php</b> on line
<b>23</b>
<br />
```

please help me out.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];


     $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = '$username' AND password ='$password'";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $response=array();


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1)
    {
        $data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)
        $response['success'] = 'true';  
        $response["name"] = $data['name'];
        $response["age"] = $data['age'];
        $response["username"] = $data['username'];
        $response["password"] = $data['password'];

    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<1){
        $response["success"] = 'false'; 

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Comment: We won't do you homework for you.  Where is line 23, what have you tried to solve the issue etc..

Comment: YIKES! You are using plain text password!!!! PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: $data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result) in this line forgot to put ";". it should $data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);

Answer (score 0):

You lack a semicolon (**;**) at the end of this line:

```
$data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)
                                ^
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made small mistake to **concatenation of  php variable with a string** in the SQL query. Please fins below the corrected one.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];


     $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password ='".$password."'";
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $response=array();


    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1)
    {
        $data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);
        $response['success'] = 'true';  
        $response["name"] = $data['name'];
        $response["age"] = $data['age'];
        $response["username"] = $data['username'];
        $response["password"] = $data['password'];

    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)<1){
        $response["success"] = 'false'; 

    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no array named by `data`. so `$data['name']` is not available.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1)
{
    $data=mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);//semi colon was missing
    $response['success'] = 'true';  
    $response["name"] = $data['name'];//unable to find $data array
    $response["age"] = $data['age'];//unable to find $data array
    $response["username"] = $data['username'];//unable to find $data array
    $response["password"] = $data['password'];//unable to find $data array

}
```